# Freezing with multiple Mei's

Tags: overwatch

So, I was wondering if more then one Mei are using the freeze attack on a target, does it freeze faster?

Comment: Based on a single Mei using her Endothermic Blaster in conjunction with Blizzard, I'd say no, but I haven't tested.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

**No**

During Closed Beta, multiple Meis using their primary fire would freeze a target faster, but the Nov 18 patch removed this ability.

From http://us.battle.net/forums/en/overwatch/topic/19892439723:

> HERO BALANCE CHANGES:
>
> > Mei
> >
> > > If multiple Meis are attacking the same target, their freeze effects will no longer stack

Comment: Aha! I thought so.

Comment: i am officially confused now

Comment: @Shaeldon Why confused? That video is very very old indeed.

Comment: Interestingly enough, that video was posted on Nov 17th, one day before the patch that removed the ability.

Comment: @DanmakuGrazer yeah noticed that now, sad though, it was a very nice one

Comment: It's fun to imagine 6 Mei's running through the map, flash-freezing and headshotting all opposition... it's also easy to see why that was nerfed.

Comment: @DavidS - Well, they could have made it a multiplier instead of straight stacking?

Answer (score 3):

<strike>If you freeze someone with multiple Mei's it goes faster.</strike>

Source:

Turns out this part is no longer relevant.

Comment: Oh what an interesting video.